# Using Hibernate @SQLDelete for Soft Delete across All Entities

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

We have a fairly complex data model and are using Hibernate and Spring Data JPA on top of MySQL.  We have a base class that all domain objects extend to minimize boiler plate code.  I would like to be able to add soft delete functionality across all of our domain objects using only this class.  However, `@SQLDelete` requires the table name in the clause:

```
@SQLDelete(sql="UPDATE (table_name) SET deleted = '1' WHERE id = ?")
@Where(clause="deleted <> '1'")
```

Does anybody know of a way to generalize the SQLDelete statement and allow the extending domain objects to populate their own table names?

Comment: We would be using this in our own version of AbstractAudible, which extends Spring Data's Persistable.

Answer (score 5):

If you use hibernate and `@SQLDelete`, there's no easy solution to your question. But you can consider another approach to soft delete with Spring Data's expression language:

```
@Override
@Query("select e from #{#entityName} e where e.deleteFlag=false")
public List<T> findAll();

//recycle bin
@Query("select e from #{#entityName} e where e.deleteFlag=true")
public List<T> recycleBin(); 

@Query("update #{#entityName} e set e.deleteFlag=true where e.id=?1")
@Modifying
public void softDelete(String id); 
//#{#entityName} will be substituted by concrete entity name automatically.
```

Rewrite base repository like this. All sub repository interfaces will have soft delete ability.

Comment: easy and clear solution, thanks. but don't forget @Transactional annotation for update-method or the whole class. as almost beginner, took me some time to find out...

Answer (score 2):

Another approach, which could be more flexible.

On Entity level create

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class SoftDeletableEntity {

    public static final String SOFT_DELETED_CLAUSE = "IS_DELETED IS FALSE";

    @Column(name = "is_deleted")
    private boolean isDeleted;
    ...

}
```

Update your Entity which should be soft deletable

```
@Entity
@Where(clause = SoftDeletableEntity.SOFT_DELETED_CLAUSE)
@Table(name = "table_name")
public class YourEntity extends SoftDeletableEntity  {...}
```

Create a custom Interface Repository which extends the Spring's Repository. Add default methods for soft delete. It should be as a base repo for your Repositories. e.g.

```
    @NoRepositoryBean
    public interface YourBaseRepository<T, ID> extends JpaRepository<T, ID> {


        default void softDelete(T entity) {

            Assert.notNull(entity, "The entity must not be null!");
            Assert.isInstanceOf(SoftDeletableEntity.class, entity, "The entity must be soft deletable!");

            ((SoftDeletableEntity)entity).setIsDeleted(true);
            save(entity);
        }

        default void softDeleteById(ID id) {

            Assert.notNull(id, "The given id must not be null!");
            this.softDelete(findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new EmptyResultDataAccessException(
                    String.format("No %s entity with id %s exists!", "", id), 1)));
        }


    }
```

NOTE: If your application doesn't have the hard delete then you could add

```
    String HARD_DELETE_NOT_SUPPORTED = "Hard delete is not supported.";

    @Override
    default void deleteById(ID id) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException(HARD_DELETE_NOT_SUPPORTED);
    }

    @Override
    default void delete(T entity) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException(HARD_DELETE_NOT_SUPPORTED);
    }

    @Override
    default void deleteAll(Iterable<? extends T> entities) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException(HARD_DELETE_NOT_SUPPORTED);
    }

    @Override
    default void deleteAll() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException(HARD_DELETE_NOT_SUPPORTED);
    }
```

Hope it could be useful.

Comment: Nice approach for overriding delete() and throw the error. But, is there any way I can do these at the global level, otherwise, I need to write in all repository. Code duplicacy.